# Element not ready after Backbone.Marionette.ItemView render?

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, marionette

I'm unable to access an element even in the onRender method of a Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.

For example, I have:

Template:

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox">`
```

ItemView:

```
View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend
    template: searchTemplate
    onRender:
        @setTypeahead ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    setTypeahead: (valueArray) ->
        console.log $('#searchBox')
        $('#searchBox').typeahead
            source: valueArray
```

Unexpectedly, the object logged to the console does NOT contain the input element. The selector didn't work. Why is that?

The comments inside the tiny code block on Marionette's github [here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#render--onrender-event) mentions "manipulate the `el` here. it's already been rendered, and is full of the view's HTML, ready to go." Unless I've misunderstood that, I would think the template would be rendered and ready to manipulate inside the onRender function of the ItemView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to scope your jQuery selector to the view, because the HTML elements are not yet added to the DOM.

```
View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend
    template: searchTemplate
    onRender:
        @setTypeahead ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    setTypeahead: (valueArray) ->
        console.log $('#searchBox')

        @$('#searchBox').typeahead
            source: valueArray
```

The reason using `onShow` works, is because the elements are added to the DOM at that point. But this is a bad idea because it would allow the selector to find all elements with the specified query in the page, not just the one for this specific view instance. By using `@$("#searchBox")` you are scoping the jQuery selector to the view instance, and are able to find the element within the view's `$el` even if the view has not been added to the DOM yet.

Comment: I do indeed like this better than using onShow. And, actually, knowing to scope to the view instance will be quite helpful in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

OK, of course as soon as I finally decide to ask here, I answer the question myself.

I should be using `onShow` instead of `onRender`. The Marionette documentation still seems to be misleading, IMO.

Comment: Yup, it also take me a while to understand the difference.